# Elastic APM Stack on Docker

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch, kibana

im trying to install the Elastic APM with Elasticsearch, Kibana and the APM server as 3 services with docker-compose. Now im getting confused on how to set the IPs in the app-server.yml file with the documentation [APM Server Configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/server/current/apm-server-configuration.html). The file should look like this:

```
apm-server:
  host: localhost:8200

output:
  elasticsearch:
    hosts: ElasticsearchAddress:9200
```

I tried to set ElasticsearchAddress to localhost or 127.0.0.1 but I always get errors like
`Failed to connect: Get http://127.0.0.1:9200: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9200: getsockopt: connection refused` or `Failed to connect: Get http://localhost:9200: dial tcp [::1]:9200: connect: cannot assign requested address`. I also tried it with several other ips.

Does anyone know how to configure the app server correctly or are there any docker-compose files to do the installation correctly?

Thanks for ur help

Answer (score 4):

If you are starting all the services with single docker compose file, the app-server.yaml should have the value like this

`output:
  elasticsearch:
    hosts: elasticsearch:9200`

The "hosts: elasticsearch:9200" should be service name of the elasticsearch you mentioned in the docker-compose. Like in the followiing

`version: '2'
    services:
      elasticsearch:
          image: elasticsearch:latest`

Answer (score 0):

When you bring up containers using compose, each container has its own networking stack (so they can each talk to themselves on `localhost`, but they need an ip address or dns name to talk to a different container!).

Compose by default connects each of the containers to a default network and gives each a dns name with the name of the service.

If your compose file looks like

```
services:
  apm:
    image: apm_image
  elasticsearch:
     image: elasticsearch:latest
```

A process in the `apm` container could access elasticsearch at `http://elasticsearch:9200`